# New Toshiba laptop used without the battery installed needs date and time set on every boot

Tags: laptop, toshiba-laptop, clock

I have a new Toshiba laptop, and I use this machine with the battery out.Every time I start my laptop, I have to set manually time and date.Is there a setting in bios that would solve my problem?I also have a Asus which work with the battery disconnected also, and I have no problem with time and date,Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would either return it to place of purchase for a full refund or contact Toshiba warranty support to get the cmos battery replaced.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small internal battery that keeps the Real Time Clock (RTC) running.  This is often known as the "CMOS Battery".  This should last for years before it needs replacing.  However, on some laptops this is a rechargeable battery, and it might need the battery in place to keep it charged.

I would experiment and see if with the laptop battery in place for a while, and with the mains connected, the CMOS battery charges and the RTC keeps it's time after the battery is removed for a for a few days.

How long it keeps it's charge could be just a few days, but I would expect you'd get at least a month out of it before it needed charging again.  Experimentation is your only hope here, unless you can get the technical docs for the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

If settings like date and time don't persist, the internal battery on the motherboard might be defective. The battery is powering the clock when your pc is turned off.

Comment: Yes. It's commonly called the "CMOS battery", and is often a coin-cell type battery mounted directly on the motherboard or connected to it with a short cable. If the laptop is new, OP should be able to have that replaced under warranty with no hassle; it's a five-minute fix.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the battery back in but barring that, you *can* change the time in BIOS. Simply turn the laptop on and before it gets to the startup screen, hit F2. The hour, minute and second fields should pop up and you can enter the correct time. Move from field to field by hitting TAB. Then press the down arrow to get to System Date. When you're done there, simply find and click on the BOOT tab. Select save changes and then hit enter. Hope this helps!

Comment: How does this help? The laptop isn't remembering the time so they'll have to perform this procedure every time they boot. That's just as bad as using any other way of setting the time each time the laptop boots, such as using the operating system's date/time functionality.